# Current time displays ugly code, before data

Tags: javascript, html

We have a web page set up to display a pair of IP cameras (using tables) with buttons to pull new images. There is a "Current time" display line coded as shown –

```
<snip>
Current time: <span id='nowtime'>, new Date().toLocaleString(), </span> 
<script>
if (document.getElementById) onload = function () 
    { setInterval ("document.getElementById ('nowtime').firstChild.data = new Date().toLocaleString()", 50) }
</script>   
</snip>
```

The problem is, when we [or timer, via a meta refresh command] activate the image refresh, the "current time" display stays showing these ugly code fragments – "Current time:, new Date().toLocaleString()," for more than a second before relaxing to the correct form – "Current time: 8/15/2022, 6:59:53 PM" information.

Is there a way to suppress that ugliness?

Comment: Easy. Don't put the ugly code there in the first place. It's javascript. Which does not belong in a span anyway

Comment: Oh, also I should stipulate that the "current time" is continuously updating each second, without intervention. It works, as shown, just ugly for a second or two when page is refreshed.

Comment: then don't put the ugly text in the span

Comment: I would appreciate a clue as to how to do it better, rather than repeated "don't do this". I have tried other variants, but they generally fail to update each second.

Comment: what is so hard about removing text? It couldn't be said simpler ..  `Current time: <span id='nowtime'></span>`